# GTK::main::run segfaults

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, gtkmm

I'm trying to write a GTK program. I managed to get my window to spawn with a button in it, but now when I try to pack a box and add 2 buttons to the box I segfault. What confuses me is that it doesn't segfault when I create anything, but insead when i run GTK::Main::run.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app =
    Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv,
    "org.gtkmm.examples.base");

    MainWindow mainWindow;
    cout << "trying to run window"<< endl;
    Gtk::Main::run(mainWindow);
    cout << "done running window"<< endl;
    return 0;
 }
```

and

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
:quit_button("Quit"),
write_button("Write"),
window_box()
{
set_border_width(10);
quit_button.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this,
    &MainWindow::quit_button_clicked));
write_button.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this,
    &MainWindow::write_button_clicked));
window_box.start_pack(quit_button);
window_box.start_pack(write_button);
add(window_box);
write_button.show();
quit_button.show();
window_box.show();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}

void MainWindow::write_button_clicked()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}
void MainWindow::quit_button_clicked()
{
    exit(0);
}
```

are my main method and my constructor for my MainWindow class. I've tried not packing anything or packing less things and I still segfault. I'm brand new to GTK so I know I must be missing something simple.

Edit: Main Window Declaration

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MainWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
public:
    MainWindow();
    ~MainWindow();

protected:
//Signal Handlers
 void   write_button_clicked();
 void   quit_button_clicked();


//Widgets
 Gtk::Button quit_button;
 Gtk::Button write_button;
 Gtk::VBox window_box;asd

};
#endif // GTKMM_EXAMPLE_HELLOWORLD_H
```

Comment: It's the GTK::Box creation. Anyone know why?

Comment: Can you can post MainWindow declaration?

Comment: Done. Thanks!   I also put this through valgrind and it's finding issues in a library, so I'm starting to think it's not something i I'm able to fix easily.

Comment: The only thing odd I see is you're creating a `Gtk::Application` but then using `Gtk::Main` to run.  `Gtk::Application` has its own `run()` method, so you should probably use that.  I don't know if that's the problem though.

Answer (score 1):

`Gtk::Main` has been deprecated and replaced by `Gtk::Application`, it handles the event loop now.

It works if instead of `Gtk::Main::run(mainWindow);` you use `app->run(mainWindow);`
like [ergosys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773846/gtkmainrun-segfaults?rq=1#comment18954839_13773846) said.

For proper cleanup, you should probably call `app->quit()` instead of libc's `quit()`, too (or just close the window, which will terminate the main loop too)